# mysql select with group by returning rows with a preference order

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, having

I have the following mysql query result:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id |   title    |     lang    | 
+----+------------+--------------
| 1  | ola1       |  1          | 
| 1  | hello1     |  2          |
| 1  | bonjour1   |  3          |
| 2  | ola2       |  1          | 
| 2  | bonjour2   |  3          |
| 3  | hello3     |  2          |
| 4  | bonjour4   |  3          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

What I want is a group_by query by id and that gives me for each id the title with  a order of preference for lang field. Example:

Result for lang preference order 1, 2, 3:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id |   title    |     lang    | 
+----+------------+--------------
| 1  | ola1       |  1          | 
| 2  | ola2       |  1          | 
| 3  | hello3     |  2          |
| 4  | bonjour4   |  3          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Result for lang preference order 3, 2, 1:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id |   title    |     lang    | 
+----+------------+--------------
| 1  | bonjour1   |  3          | 
| 2  | bonjour2   |  3          | 
| 3  | hello3     |  2          |
| 4  | bonjour4   |  3          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why are the lang values out of order (3,3,2,3) in your second resultset example: what logic generated that order? WIll `ORDER BY lang ASC` or `...DESC` do it for you, or am I missing something? Why `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Hi Ollie! Thanks for your answer. I said group by because I want one row for each id and this is done with group by keyword. However I want to be able to choose which row will be selected based in the lang field. So lets say that I have a preference for language 1 and then 2 and then 3. I want to return for each id the row with lang=1 if theres an row with that lang, if not choose lang=2, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either not possible, or, not with in my SQL skills to execute that in one query. I always end up using a temporary template and two SQL commands for these problems:

(assuming that your table is called Table1 and the temporary table should be called tempTable)

```
SELECT Table1.id, Min(Table1.lang) AS Min_Of_lang INTO tempTable FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.id ORDER BY Table1.id;
SELECT Table1.* FROM tempTable INNER JOIN Table1 ON (tempTable.MinOflang = Table1.lang) AND (tempTable.id = Table1.id);
```

The first command creates a new table (that overrides the current table if it exists). The second command uses the first table to produce the desired result set.

To change from your first desired results table to the second, use Max instead of min in the first query.

Somebody else may well have a more elegant solution than mine. Also, an extra SQL statement could be added to delete the temporary table.

Comment: Yes...Unfortunaly I think is not possible too in one query... I think I will do the row selection in the application layer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature that is not defined in MySQL. The displayed value in a non-aggregated column is undetermined. [read more here (MySQL Documentation)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

(Standard SQL doesn't allow to include non-aggregated columns when using GROUP BY, I guess this is one of the reasons).

From your description of the what you want to do, you should simple SELECT all rows with the lang you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE lang = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will not work because is not granted that I will have the lang = 1 for each id. In that case I would like the select to return other language based on a defined preference order for lang.